# (Boolean. false) in Clojure

Tags: clojure, jvm, boolean

According to http://hyperpolyglot.org/lisp, the only falsehoods in Clojure are `false` and `nil`. Indeed, surprisingly enough, `(Boolean. false)` is not false:

```
user=> (if (Boolean. false) 1 2)
1
user=> (not (Boolean. false))
false
user=> (false? (Boolean. false))
false
```

On the other hand, it somehow *is* false:

```
user=> (class false)
java.lang.Boolean
user=> (= false (Boolean. false))
true
```

This is rather counterintuitive. Are there reasons for this behaviour or was it simply overlooked?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find the explanation at http://clojure.org/special_forms#if.

It's good to read the whole paragraph, but here's the crucial bit excerpted, emphasis added:

> [...] All [...] conditionals in Clojure are based upon the same logic, that is, **nil** and **false** constitute logical falsity, and everything else constitutes logical truth, and those meanings apply throughout. [...] *Note that ***if*** does not test for arbitrary values of java.lang.Boolean, only the singular value false (Java's Boolean.FALSE), so if you are creating your own boxed Booleans make sure to use Boolean/valueOf and not the Boolean constructors.*

Compare

```java
System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(false) ? true : false);  // false
System.out.println(new Boolean(false)     ? true : false);  // false
```

with

```
user=> (if (Boolean/valueOf false) true false)
false
user=> (if (Boolean. false) true false)
true
```

Thus, `(Boolean. false)` is neither `nil` nor `false`, just as `(Object.)` is neither `nil` nor `false`. And as @Chiron has pointed out, it's bad practice to use it anyway.

As for `(= false (Boolean. false))` being true, I think @looby's explanation is spot on: Since `=` relies on Java's `equals` method, the special semantics of conditionals in Clojure don't apply, and boolean equality will be as it is in Java.

Answer (score 6):

Don't ever and never call (Boolean. true) or (Boolean. "true"). Don't create any instance of Boolean class. Those two forms are really evil.

This isn't an issue of Clojure, actually it is a Java's one.

There are only two possible values for a boolean: true or false which are already provided by Java. The constructors give you the illusion that you can create a new instance of Boolean class that can behave as a Boolean but it won't.

If you really want to create a Boolean instance from a String or a boolean, then use valueOf() method of Boolean class.

```
(Boolean/valueOf "true")
(Boolean/valueOf  true)
```

[Boolean.html#valueOf(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28boolean%29)

Comment: As the rest of the post explains, they look like they will create a usable boolean, but they do not. This can cause weird hard to track bugs.

Comment: @noisesmith Yes indeed and that is why no one should try to create a Boolean instance by calling the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't quite see why this is a Java's issue. I mean, in Java, `new Boolean(false)` does behave in if-clauses just as one would expect (although I don't see a use for it).

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason this happens is that [Clojure's =](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/=) uses Java's `equals` method. So `(= x y)` is like `x.equals(y)`. So `false` gets coerced into `(Boolean. false)` in the comparison under the hood.

Note that this does not mean that `(Boolean. false)` *is false* or that it *is the 'same' as false*, just that when `false` and `(Boolean. false)` are compared using the `equals` method they are considered to be equal.

Comment: But

    user=> (.equals (Boolean. "true") (Boolean/valueOf "true"))